Is there a way to simplify the following expression without involving the imaginary parts, which we know should vanish?
Consider the following expression that arises from solving an infinite integral using the residue method:
$$
F = \frac{\pi}{4\alpha\beta} \left( J_0(bz_1) H_0^{(1)}(\sigma z_1) - J_0(bz_2) H_0^{(1)}(\sigma z_2) \right) \, ,
$$
where $ z_1 = \alpha + i\beta $ and $ z_2 = -\alpha + i\beta $, with $ 0 \leq \alpha \leq \beta \leq 1 $ and $ 0 < b \leq \sigma $.
Here, $J_0$ and $ H_0^{(1)} $ denote the Bessel and Hankel function of the first kind of order zero, respectively.
In the simplistic situation in which $ \alpha = 0 $ and $ \beta = 1 $, such that $ z_1 = z_2 = i $, it can easily be shown that this equation simplifies to
$$
F = \sigma I_0(b)K_1(\sigma) - bI_1(b)K_0(\sigma) \, .
$$
I am wondering if an simplified expression can similarly be obtained for the general case. I am specifically looking for an expression involving Bessel functions of real arguments, containing $\alpha$ and $\beta$, or a combination of both, without involving complex numbers.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

@YvesDaoust If you can present your solution, even if it's in the form of a finite series expansion, that would be great.

I would be very surprised if $F$ can be expressed in terms of Bessel functions of real arguments.   But for $\alpha, \beta, b, \sigma >0$, $F$ can be expressed as   $$F= \frac{\pi}{2 \alpha \beta} \Bigg( \Re \left(J_{0}(bz_{1}) \right) \Re \left(H_{0}^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1}) \right) - \Im \left(J_{0}(b z_{1}) \right) \Im \left(H_{0}^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1}) \right) \Bigg), $$ which shows that it's indeed real valued.

@RandomVariable Thanks

The following answer expands on my comment.

Assume that $\alpha$, $\beta$, $b$ and $\sigma$ are all positive parameters.
While it's unlikely that $F$ can be expressed in terms of Bessel functions of real arguments, $F$ can be expressed in a way that shows that it's real valued.
Since $J_{0}(z)$ and the principal branch of $iH_{0}^{(1)}(z)$ are both analytic in the upper half-plane and real valued on the positive imaginary axis, it follows from the Schwarz reflection principle (by reflecting over the positive imaginary axis) that $$J_{0}(bz_{2})= \Re \left( J_{0}(bz_{1}) \right)-i \, \Im \left( J_{0}(bz_{1}) \right) $$ and $$iH_{0}^{(1)}(\sigma z_{2}) = \Re \left( i H_{0}^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1}) \right)-i \, \Im  \left( i H_{0}^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1})\right) = - \Im \left(H_{0}^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1}) \right)-i \, \Re \left(H_{0}^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1}) \right).$$
(For $x>0$, $J_{0}(ix) = I_{0}(x)$ and $iH_{0}^{(1)}(ix) = \frac{2 K_{0}(x)}{\pi}$.)
Therefore, $$ \begin{align} F &= \frac{\pi}{4\alpha\beta} \left[ J_0(bz_{1}) H_0^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1}) - J_0(bz_{2}) H_0^{(1)}(\sigma z_{2}) \right] \\ &= \small \frac{\pi}{4\alpha\beta} \left[J_0(bz_{1}) H_0^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1})- \big( \Re \left( J_{0}(bz_{1})\right)-i \, \Im \left(  J_{0}(b z_{1}) \right)\big) \left( - \Re \left(H_{0}^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1})\right) + i \, \Im \left(H_{0}^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1}) \right) \right) \right] \\ &= \frac{\pi}{4\alpha\beta} \Big[\big(\Re \left(J_{0}(b z_{1}) \right) + i \, \Im \left(J_{0}(b z_{1}) \right)\big) \left(\Re \left(H_{0}^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1}) \right) + i \, \Im \left(H_{0}^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1}) \right)  \right)\\ &- \big( \Re \left( J_{0}(bz_{1})\right)-i \, \Im \left(   J_{0}(b z_{1}) \right)\big) \left( - \Re \left(H_{0}^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1})\right) + i \, \Im \left(H_{0}^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1}) \right) \right)  \Big] \\ &= \frac{\pi}{2\alpha \beta} \left[\Re \left( J_{0}(b z_{1})  \right) \Re \left(H_{0}^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1}) \right) - \Im \left( J_{0}(b z_{1})  \right) \Im \left(H_{0}^{(1)}(\sigma z_{1}) \right)\right]. \end{align}$$
